# Error en java Exception in thread "main"

Tags: java

El error que presenta es:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line
>   found at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source).

Tengo un metodo readAddress que obtiene los valores de la clase. Este metodo es llamado desde otra clase `Employee` para leer la `Address` del `Employee` entre otros atributos. Adjunto los dos metodos. Cuando testeo los metodos por separado funciona bien.

```
public void readAddress() {

    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    String string;

    System.out.println("Address(Separate each data with '/'): ");
    string = read.nextLine();

    String[] substring = string.split("/");

    this.building = substring[0];
    this.apartment = substring[1];
    this.street = substring[2];
    this.city = substring[3];
    this.province = substring[4];
    this.code = substring[5];
    read.close();
}

public void readEmployee() {

    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Last name: ");
    this.lastname = read.nextLine();
    System.out.println("First name: ");
    this.firstname = read.nextLine();
    this.email.readEmail();
    this.address.readAddress();
    this.telephone.readTelephone();
    System.out.println("Social security number: ");
    this.ssn = read.nextLine();
    read.close();
}
```

El error esta sobre la linea:

```
string = read.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

La api de java dice sobre el método readLine() lo siguiente:

> Throws:
>       NoSuchElementException - if no line was found  You are supposed to handle this exception or just use the hasNextLine() method to avoid
>   the exception.

Se supone que debes manejar esta excepcion o simplemente usar el método hasNextLine() para evitar la excepcion.

```
while(read.hasNextLine()){
    ssn= read.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

es un poco tarde pero espero le sirva a alguien de la comunidad que haya buscado como yo.
La solucion que encontre es inicializar el Scanner por fuera de las funciones y de forma Static para que pueda acceder en todas ellas.

```
static Scanner registro = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Por algun motivo (que todavia no entiendo) arroja la excepcion al querer inicializar Scanners por separado